# Why aren't my git logs logged in git and github?

Tags: git, github, commit

I did commit and push in terminal,
I checked that the file was properly uploaded to Github.

[image]

However, it was recorded as no contribution in Github, and my commit was not recorded in the Git log.

[image]
[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

p.s.
I'm not familiar with the question, so the information is a bit lacking. I'm sorry.

Comment: what page are you checking the 'contribution', or 'logs'? please paste the url.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Please post all the messages / logs, which makes you know "it was ... no contribution, ... not recorded in ... log" by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your local Git configuration file contains an email address that is registered to your GitHub account. The [GitHub setup guide](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/quickstart/set-up-git) will help you do that for your platform.

If the commits were made with another email address, just add that address to your GitHub account and the commits will be attributed to you.

Comment: This GitHub support document contains more details about how the commits are attributed to a GitHub profile: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-graphs-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile

Comment: Thanks for answering.

There was a part where I misunderstood this issue.
My default branch is not master, but it was not displayed on the dashboard because I committed to the master branch.

Thanks everyone for taking the time to reply.
And I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone,
I have very little knowledge of git.

I proceeded with git commit while looking for old codes,
In the past, the default branch was all master, so
All the codes I saw were explained to commit to the master branch.

But now, since the main branch is the default branch, it seems that the codes I uploaded to the master branch were not displayed on the dashboard.

Sorry to confuse everyone.
Thank you.